# ValueError: invalid shape for input data points in griddata operation

Tags: scipy

I am running into an error when using scipy.interpolate.griddata. My goal is to prepare data for contouring using matplotlib. I have read that the best way to perform this is to separate the x any y as 1D arrays using linspace before passing to griddata.

The min and max values of my x and y values are used to input into the linspace, so as to keep the co-ordinates the same for GIS mapping purposes (not sure if this is necessary to have the data points in the same xy area as the grid co-ordinates, but am doing so any way)

The file Watertable CSV is imported as a numpy array with x,y and z values. The z is supplied to griddata as a straight array column index.

I am running into the error "valueError: invalid shape for input data points"

I am sure it is something very simple and hopefully someone can shed light on my error.

[EDIT]

I have linked the csv file using pastebin as suggested:

http://pastebin.com/nj7THgMw

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from numpy import genfromtxt


my_data = genfromtxt('WaterTable.csv', delimiter=',')
x = my_data[1:,0:1]
y = my_data[1:,1:2]
z = my_data[1:,2:3]

xmax = max(x)
xmin = min(x)
ymax = max(y)
ymin = min(y)

xi = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 2000)

yi = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 2000)

zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='cubic')
```

I script then exits with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Hp/PycharmProjects/GISdev/Irregular_Grid03.py", line 60, in <module>
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='cubic')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\ndgriddata.py", line 212, in griddata
rescale=rescale)
File "scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx", line 840, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.__init__ (scipy\interpolate\interpnd.c:9961)
File "scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx", line 78, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.NDInterpolatorBase.__init__ (scipy\interpolate\interpnd.c:2356)
File "scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx", line 123, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.NDInterpolatorBase._check_init_shape (scipy\interpolate\interpnd.c:3128)
ValueError: invalid shape for input data points
```

Comment: Someone can probably eyeball this one but for those of us who can't, your csv will make it easier to investigate. I think you can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) if you don't have a way to host it.

Comment: Thanks, just updated with a link to the csv paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays `x`, `y` and `z` are *two-dimensional*, with shape `(n, 1)`.  `griddata` expects *one-dimensional* arrays (i.e. with shape `(n,)`).

To fix this, use a single index instead of a slice in the second index position when you pull the arrays out of `my_data`:

```
x = my_data[1:, 0]
y = my_data[1:, 1]
z = my_data[1:, 2]
```

Comment: Warren, what should xi, yi be to represent a cartesian space?