# Error during contouring of griddata - Length of x must be number of columns in z, and length of y must be number of rows

Tags: numpy, scipy, contour

This question is a follow on from a previous problem I'm having with contouring data points that is detailed here.

[[ValueError: invalid shape for input data points in griddata operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165900/valueerror-invalid-shape-for-input-data-points-in-griddata-operation/32166676#32166676][1])

After executing the griddata successfully, which required x and y as 1D and z to be a 2D array, I get the following error in relation to contour module:

"TypeError: Length of x must be number of columns in z, and length of y must be number of rows."

Which logically makes sense to me, as the X,Y position of Z must be known for the correct datum to be input. Short of making a square 2D array with NaN for all positions other than the points which contain Z data, is there a more elegant solution?

I would assume that the griddata being generated incorporates some kind of xy locating for z on an indexing basis, however this may not be the case and infact xy locations may need to be specified precisely in an array. This seems to be doubling up to me and something I would presume the griddata module would handle.

If anyone can shed light on the correct process for contouring from griddata, it would be helpful.

As always, thank you for your time and assistance.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as ml
import numpy.ma as ma
from numpy.random import uniform, seed
from numpy import genfromtxt

my_data = genfromtxt('WaterTable.csv', delimiter=',')
# Data imported as a 2D array
z = my_data[1:,2:3]

#Data imported as 1D array
x = my_data[1:, 0]
y = my_data[1:, 1]

xmax = max(x)
xmin = min(x)
ymax = max(y)
ymin = min(y)

# Prepares for import to griddata
xi = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 2000)
yi = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 2000)

# grids data
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='cubic')
# contour the gridded data

CS = plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,15,linewidths=0.5,colors='k')
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,15,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar() # draw colorbar

# plot data points.

plt.scatter(x,y,marker='o',c='b',s=5)
plt.xlim(-2,2)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.title('griddata test (%d points)' % npts)
plt.show()
```

Error thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Hp/PycharmProjects/GISdev/Irregular_Grid04.py", line 30, in <module>
CS = plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,15,linewidths=0.5,colors='k')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2188, in contour
ret = ax.contour(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 7316, in contour
return mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 1106, in __init__
ContourSet.__init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 700, in __init__
self._process_args(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 1119, in _process_args
x, y, z = self._contour_args(args, kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 1166, in _contour_args
x,y,z = self._check_xyz(args[:3], kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 1208, in _check_xyz
"and length of y must be number of rows.")
TypeError: Length of x must be number of columns in z, and length of y must be number of rows.
```

Comment: I'd throw in a print statement right before the `coutour` to check the shape of `xi, yi, zi`.  Better yet run this script in an interactive shell and look at variables at several points along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rereading your question I realized that `gridata` is calculating one `zi` value for each `(xi,yi)` pair, ie `2000`.  But those values are just linear. - generated by `linspace`.  To `contour` they need to form a Cartesian space.  That's what my example does.  Your `xi`, `yi` valuus need to go through `meshgrid` (or equivalent) before being passed to `gridata`.

My contouring example is valid, but my guess as to what is wrong with your shapes was off.  The problem is before `gridata`, not after.

---

A basic step when debugging `numpy` code is to print the shape of arrays at various points, especially when the error talks about their length.  Another is to construct simple test cases in an interactive shell (I use Ipython).

Let's try the contour step:

```
In [32]: xi=np.arange(10)    
In [33]: yi=np.arange(15)
In [34]: zi=xi[:,None]+yi[None,:]
In [35]: zi.shape
Out[35]: (10, 15)
```

`zi` is a function of `xi` and `yi` - the 1st and 2nd dimensions

** that's 10 x 15, not just 10 or 15 **

```
In [36]: plt.contour(xi,yi,zi)
....
TypeError: Length of x must be number of columns in z,
and length of y must be number of rows.
```

That's your error message right?

Try it again, but using the transpose of `zi`:

```
In [37]: plt.contour(xi,yi,zi.T)
Out[37]: <matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet instance at 0xa32726c>
```

works.  So does `plt.contour(yi,xi,zi)`; and `plt.contour(zi)` (of course axis labels are wrong).

Without going to all the work of setting up a `my_data` that will work in `griddata`, I suspect this switch of `xi` and `yi` (of the .T) will solve things.

But!  you are using `linspace(...,2000)` for both, so maybe they have the same length and `zi` is square.

Another possibility is that `z` has a wrong shape.  I'm guessing `x` and `y` are `(n,)`, and `z` is `(n,1)` (due to the 2:3).  How does that pass through the `griddata` to `zi`?  I don't have a working example for `griddata` so can't test it.

You need to print the shape of all of these arrays.  Otherwise we have to deduce from experience, or run our own dummy test cases.  We shouldn't have to go to all that work to help you debug your code.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. The shape function is very useful and I have manage to correct the script. Using it, I found that the z matrix was indeed 1D and not 2D as you suggested. I will post the fixed code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help and advice on debugging numpy arrays. Just wanted to post up the working code for this. In the end I used ravel to reduce Z to a 2D array. Without ravel Zi returns a shape of (2000, 2000, 1) instead of (2000, 2000).  Ravel removes the extra dimension which was the problem. I think passing through meshgrid may have a similar effect.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import genfromtxt

my_data = genfromtxt('WaterTable.csv', delimiter=',')

# Data imported as a 2D array
z = my_data[1:,2:3]

#Data imported as 1D array
x = my_data[1:, 0]
y = my_data[1:, 1]

xmax = max(x)
xmin = min(x)
ymax = max(y)
ymin = min(y)

# Prepares for import to griddata
xi = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 2000)
yi = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 2000)

# grids data
zi = griddata((x, y), z.ravel(), (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
# contour the gridded data

print(zi.shape)
print(xi.shape)
print(yi.shape)

CS = plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,15,linewidths=0.5,colors='k')
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,15,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar() # draw colorbar

# plot data points.
plt.scatter(x,y,marker='o',c='b',s=5)
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
plt.show()
```